# How to search for a user profile by calling LinkedIn App from my own app?

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

I have the information of a person and I wasnt to look that person up on LinkedIn using my own app.

So, I can call the search activity from LinkedIn using

```
Intent linkedinIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
linkedinIntent.setClassName("com.linkedin.android", "com.linkedin.android.search.SearchActivity");

startActivity(linkedinIntent);
```

Now, I want to be able to pass some parameters to it, like the name, so that it can search the person on the linkedIn and display his profile. Is there anyway to do this?

About "com.linkedin.android.search.SearchActivity", I know this because I wrote code to find all the activities in the LinkedIn App, and also ran it. All suggestions other than using the inbuild LinkedIn app are more than welcome :)

Best,
Ankit

P.S: I have the OAuth Keys already generated if need-be.